# Using Javascript to Add Values From a Textbox That Came From PHP

Tags: javascript, php, textbox, addition

I have 3 text boxes whose values came from PHP and I want to add them using Javascript.

so I have this code:

```
function addNumbers()      
  { 
   var pa    = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pa").value) ||0;
   var ma    = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ma").value) ||0;
   var oa    = parseFloat(document.getElementById("oa").value) ||0;
   var ga    = document.getElementById("ga");      

   ga.value = (pa+ma+oa).toFixed(2);
}
```

and in my HTML, I have this:

```
<input onchange="addNumbers()" type="text" id="pa" name="pa" value="<?php echo $pas_Sum ?>" /> 
<input onchange="addNumbers()" type="text" id="ma" name="ma" value="<?php echo $mas_Sum ?>" /> 
<input onchange="addNumbers()" type="text" id="oa" name="oa" value="<?php echo $oas_Sum ?>" /> 
<input onchange="addNumbers()" type="text" id="ga" name="ga" value="" />
```

The problem: The sum is not displaying in the text box "ga"

also in PHP, I have this:

```
$pa      = mysql_query("select SUM(PAmt) as sumPA FROM $tbl_name"); 
$pa_sum  = mysql_fetch_assoc($pa); 
$pas_Sum = number_format ($pa_sum['sumPA'], 2);

$ma      = mysql_query("select SUM(MAmt) as sumMA FROM $tbl_name"); 
$ma_sum  = mysql_fetch_assoc($ma); 
$mas_Sum = number_format ($ma_sum['sumMA'], 2);

$oa      = mysql_query("select SUM(Amt) as sumOA FROM $tbl_name"); 
$oa_sum  = mysql_fetch_assoc($oa); 
$oas_Sum = number_format ($oa_sum['sumOA'], 2);
```

At first I have tried to directly add the numbers using this code:

```
$all = $pas_Sum + $mas_Sum + $oas_Sum
```

and then I put this in the HTML text box

```
<input type="text" id="ga" name="ga" value="<?php echo $all ?>" />
```

The problem in here is that it is displaying the wrong amount. That is why I have tried using JS but I am not getting any display in the textbox. Any idea on how I should solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: In the first HTML listing there is no php for the ga line. `<input onchange="addNumbers()" type="text" id="ga" name="ga" value="" /> `

Comment: what should I put there? the textbox "ga" should just contain the sum of the 3 boxes

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @Lugia101101, none. And the Javascript code - if I put ga.value = (pa.toFixed(2); to try the code, I am not STILL getting any values. In PHP code, if I put <input type="text" id="ga" name="ga" value="<?php echo $pas_Sum ?>" /> , I am getting the right value.

Comment: There must be an issue with the data that is being parsed from your php. Your code in it's current state works fine DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/a3aL6/

Comment: @Vector, any idea how to address the issue?

Comment: If you provide a link to a website I could have a quick look.

Comment: im just using the localhost. or can you try to see what's wrong with the PHP code why its not adding properly?

Comment: @Vector, why does the result not showing in the JSfiddle you have provided?

Comment: @LadyWinter it does show, edit a field and then click out of it

Comment: @LadyWinter see my answer to display the pre-filled text box on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the values to be calculated on page load then you will need to force a change event after load has completed

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/a3aL6/1/

```
(function () {
    function load2(){
        document.getElementById("ga").onchange();
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load2, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('onload', load2);
    }
} ());
```

If you want the values to change as a user changes the input, without haveing to lose focu on the element, then you could consider using `onkeyup` instead of `onchange`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/a3aL6/2/

str_replace example

```
$pas_Sum =  str_replace(',', '', $pa_sum['sumPA']);
$pas_Sum = number_format (pas_Sum, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you, I now see the issue why its not working. also why the PHP code is not giving the right answer. Its not ignoring the comma. How can I ignore the comma so that I can add? I have tried str_replace but its not working.

Comment: What does the raw php output without it being in the function `number_format`?

Comment: Thank you @Vector,  its now working except that, if there's a comma, its just getting the number before the comma. how can i ignore the comma?

Comment: Before you use the number_format function, use `str_replace(',', '', $subject); see my edit

Comment: ohh ok ill try that. What ive done is $pas_Sum = number_format (str_replace(',', '', $pa_sum['sumPA'])), 2;

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign value like this ,

```
  document.getElementsByName('ga')[0].value = ga;
```

where ga would be your sum ,

```
  ga = (pa+ma+oa).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have tried putting a constant value in the function. like this : function addNumbers(){var y=5; var ga  = document.getElementById("ga"); ga.value = (y+2);}. Still no display on the textbox

Comment: yes, i did, its now working, the issue is, if there's a comma, its just getting the number before the comma.

Comment: Can you paste last two lines of the code? So i can understand what exactly problem is.